# IA-32 assembly divison

Tags: assembly, intel

Can somebody explain to me the following snippet of assembly:

```
mydiv:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        movl    8(%ebp), %edx  ; get x
        movl    %edx, %eax
        sarl    $31, %edx      ; divide by y
        idivl   12(%ebp)       ; return %eax
        popl    %ebp
        ret
```

This is the equivalent to the following C function:

```
int mydiv( int x, int y )
{
    return x / y;
}
```

The part which I'm having trouble understanding is the `sarl` instruction: why do you need to shift `edx`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [*sign extending*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension).

`idivl` has a 64-bit argument (`edx:eax`), so you need to ensure that the MSB contains the correct sign bits, based on the msb of `eax`.

So if `eax` is positive, it's msb will be `0`, e.g. 5 -> `0000 ... 0101`.  If it's negative it's msb will be `1`, e.g. -5 -> `1111 ... 1011`.  `sarl` performs an arithmetic right-shift, so `edx` will either be `0000 ... 0000` or `1111 ... 1111`.

Comment: Could you give me an example ?